# feeding input to a java process from a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

If I have a simple java program that processes lines of text from standard input, then I can run it with the following script:

```
@Echo off
java Test < file.txt
pause
exit
```

The script redirects lines of input from file.txt into the java program.

Is there a way that I can avoid having to use a separate file? Or is this the easiest way?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you just want java to redirect your keyboard input to wherever?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to send multiple lines of input to the java program without using a file.

Comment: Can't you modify your Java main to read from args and just pass the file(s) in as parameter(s) to the main ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [pipe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx).

This trivial Java app just prints out the lines from `stdin`:

```
public class Dump {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int line = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      System.out.format("%d: %s%n", line++, scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Invoked with this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
(ECHO This is line one
ECHO This is line two; the next is empty
ECHO.
ECHO This is line four)| java -cp bin Dump
PAUSE
```

...it will print:

```
0: This is line one
1: This is line two; the next is empty
2:
3: This is line four
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know I could use parens to pipe multiple lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple:

```
$ java Test < file.txt
```

But if you absolutely need the `pause` command, you will have to do it on a script, or code pause behavior in Test class.

Comment: You can just do `java Test < file.txt & pause`